# Where do I specify the screen image used in Lock Screen?

Tags: 12.04

Ctrl-Alt-L works fine. But the image is XP Bliss and I'm kind of surprised. I probably specified this, although it's not my background wallpaper. I'm using 12.04 for now.

Answer (score 0):

you should create an xml file in `/usr/share/images/desktop-base` directory and add these lines there:

```
<background>
<static>
<duration>8640000.0</duration>
<file>
  <size width="1920" height="1200">/home/fabhax/wallpapers/NATURE-TheDivide_1920x1200.jpg</size>
</file>
</static>
</background>
```

Of course You can change the attributes with your preference.

save the file and restart your gnome :

```
/etc/init.d/gdm3 restart
```